# why Path.ends_with return false when passed a correctly-matching file extension?

Tags: rust

why this code return false

```rust
use std::path::Path;
fn main() {
    println!(
        "Ends with? {:?}",
        &Path::new("some.file.d.ts").ends_with("ts")
    );
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc9b53f9bb0bf3216aec582c5cd4e194)

Comment: As the docs say: *Only considers whole path components to match.*

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is explicit about this:

> Determines whether `child` is a suffix of `self`.
>
> **Only considers whole path components to match**

An extension like `ts` is not a whole path component.

---

So, a case where it would be true would be something like:

```rust
use std::path::Path;
fn main() {
    println!(
        "Ends with? {:?}",
        &Path::new("/path/to/some.file.d.ts").ends_with("some.file.d.ts")
    );
}
```

Comment: but how to find file with `*.d.ts` ?

Comment: You can use a normal string operation for that and not need `std::path` at all.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.extension

Comment: @neuronet, to be clear, your question _doesn't ask_ how to change your code to compare file extensions. Your question asks why your original code doesn't work to test for extensions, and that's exactly the question this answer addresses. If you wanted a different answer, you should have asked a different question.